# Set a friendly DNS name for SQL Reporting Services URL

Tags: sql-server, dns, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, system-administration

My Reporting Services URL by default on Reporting Services Configuration Manager is set to Http://{server name}/Reports 
Now I would like to give it a pair of DNS friendly names 
1- SQLReports.Com  (Internal and Not a public URL) 
2- WWW.Reports.PCProbe.com  (Global Internet address)
However, I don't know how and what steps I have to pace ?? I also cant find anything on the IIS6! Please advise.
(Win/SQL are in 2016 Version).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do it on the server where SQL is installed you can use the hostfile for that.

For the outside world you can point the DNS record to the server SQL is installed on. Make sure you allow the right firewall traffic so you enable traffic for MSSQL 1433.

Cheers!

Comment: The default SQL Server port is 1433.

Comment: Not enough for me to understand please explain more.